# cv.tree function - no error message - no calculation stop

Tags: r

I want to use the function cv.tree from the package tree. For exercise purposes I use the file 'iris' from the R data.

When using cv.tree the calculation never comes to an end nor I get an error message and I have to use the stop button. What's wrong with my code? 
My core code is like:

```
> library(party)
> data(iris)
> sample <-  sample(2, size=nrow(iris), replace=TRUE, prob=c(.7,.3))
> sampling <- cbind(iris,sample)
> traindata <- sampling[sample==1,]
> library(Formula)
> formula <- Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width 
> treemodel = ctree(formula,data=traindata)
> library(tree)
> class(treemodel) <- "tree"
> crossvalidation <- cv.tree(object=treemodel, rand=runif(nrow(traindata)), FUN=prune.tree, K=10)
```

I also used other K values and FUN=prune.misclass. 
Thanks for your help. Ciau Uwe

Comment: cv.tree function ends with "K=10)"

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

The `treemodel` object is not of class "tree". 
The fact that you have assigned the class "tree" doesn't fix this.

Compare your tree and the tree made in the example in `cv.tree`.

```
data(cpus, package="MASS")
cpus.ltr <- tree(log10(perf) ~ syct + mmin + mmax + cach
 + chmin + chmax, data=cpus)
cpus.ltr

# compare to your tree
treemodel
```

They are very different objects. 
You will have to find a way to convert from "BinaryTree" to "tree".

Secondly, the `rand` argument should take an integer vector. `runif(nrow(traindata))` gives numbers between 0 and 1 i.e. not integers.
However, `cv.tree` seems to silently ignore this argument if it is mispecified.

Comment: Your answer brings me closer to understand the bug.

Comment: When I use the tree function the problem does not appear. However I wanted to use ctree function from the party package.

Comment: Is there a way to produce a ctree function output of class "tree"?

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't find one. And I couldn't see an easy way to convert one to the other manually. Sorry.

Comment: ok think I found the answer, i.e. pruning is not required with ctree function in party package, thanks a lot for your help that gave me the right direction